# How to customize the look of currently selected(highlighted) completion in zsh?

Tags: zsh

## Main question

I would like to add powerline characters at the start and at the end of the selected completion, like this:

1. [Started the completion menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngguB.png) by inserting `c` and pressing the `TAB` key.
2. [Moved right in the completion menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PYUE.png) by pressing the right arrow key.
3. [Moved down in the completion menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo7iw.png) by pressing the down arrow key.

Is there any way to make `zsh` look/behave like in the pictures?

#### Note

Added powerline triangle + blank character at the beginning and blank character + powerline triangle at the end should somehow be accounted when columns are created to keep the alignment correct.

#### Bonus

Add 2 blanks at the beginning of **every** completion in the list, so that when the completion is selected it doesn't look like the text was moved to the right.
( This issue can be seen by comparing the completion with and without the selection. )

---

## Alternative question

In case that previously explained behavior is impossible to get without changing the `zsh` source code, is it at least possible to add powerline triangle **only** at the end of the selected completion?

---

#### My unsuccessful attempts

- I have tried using the `lc`, `rc`, and `ec` variables in the `list-colors` style but that didn't help:

  1. Completion list was badly aligned and it created all kinds of visual problems.
  2. Symbols were inserted in all elements of the completion list, not just the selected one.
- I have also tried using the `ma` variable, but I couldn't properly insert a character at the beginning:

  1. The variable expects only a number that represents a color and it is probably wrapped in some escape sequences, so the output did not look as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
zstyle ":completion:*:default" list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS} "ma=48;5;153;1"
```

Uses my LS_COLORS and then ma sets the background of my selection to bold and color 153 from https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/.